# Onitem click listner not working in list view

Tags: android

Hi in my app I want to do some functionality on click of item in a list.

Here is the xml for the list item.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:focusable="true">

    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+checklistitem/itemrow">
        <TableRow android:id="@+checklistitem/tr"> 
            <TextView android:id="@+checklistitem/texthead"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:paddingRight="0dp" android:maxLines="2" android:textSize="16dp"
                android:text="Towel Rack: 2 hand towels,2 wash clothes"
                android:background="#000000" android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"  />

            <TextView android:id="@+checklistitem/textSeparator"
            android:visibility="gone" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_width="240dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:paddingRight="0dp" android:maxLines="2" android:textSize="16dp"
                android:text=""
                android:background="#000000" android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"  />


            <TextView android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:id="@+checklistitem/inspectionvalue" android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#006699" android:text="01"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the code where I used adapter for my list

```
checklistview.setOnItemClickListener(this);


        CheckListAdapterForAtt checkAdapter = new CheckListAdapterForAtt(this.getApplicationContext(), checkListRowDataArr, R.layout.checklist_row);
```

But some how Item click listner does not working for me???

Comment: same question : define 'doesn't work'

Comment: I am having public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {} this method but on clicking the item the control is not coming on this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following in the XML row layout where you want to click

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

Onclick listener Like following

```
mList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        private void OnItemSelected() {

        }

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            if(arg2 == 0)
            {

            }

            if(arg2 == 1)
            {

            }
```